# Unable to pass a String Parameter to a Sub when using Checkbox .OnAction

Tags: excel, vba

As the title says, I am unable to pass a String parameter through an OnAction that occurs when a checkbox is checked. I have successfully passed two integer values to the sub when the checkbox is checked, but now I need to also pass a String parameter (the String is actually the name of the current Worksheet).

This is currently what it looks like:

```
'Start of for loop which will run from the lower bound of esq to the upper bound.
For i = LBound(esq) To UBound(esq)

    'Inserts a row at the specified location, the current row + 1 + the value of i (0 to 12 depending on which run of the loop it is currently on).
    workSource.Rows(rowPos + 1 + i).Insert

    'Sets cb as equal to the specified cell in the newly inserted row.
    Set cb = workSource.CheckBoxes.Add(Cells(rowPos + 1 + i, colPos + 1).Left, Cells(rowPos + 1 + i, colPos + 1).Top, _
    Cells(rowPos + 1 + i, colPos + 1).Width, Cells(rowPos + 1 + i, colPos + 1).Height)

    'Start of With which sets the attributes of cb.
    With cb

        'Sets the caption as the current element of esq.
        .Caption = esq(i)
        'Links the checkbox with the cell directly beneath it.
        .LinkedCell = Cells(rowPos + 1 + i, colPos + 1).Address
        'Adds a macro which will be activated when it is clicked. The cell's row and column position will be passed as parameters to the macro.
        .OnAction = "'ProcessCheckBox " & rowPos + 1 & "," & colPos + 1 + i & "," & currentName & "'"
        '.OnAction = "'" & ThisWorkSheet.Name & "'!ProcessCheckBox"
        '.OnAction = "'ProcessCheckBox " & rowPos + 1 & "," & colPos + 1 + i & "," & """SES""" & "'"
        '.OnAction = "'ProcessCheckBox " & currentName & "'"

    'End of With.
    End With

'Starts next run of loop and increments i.
Next i
```

There are three commented out lines of OnAction that I attempted to experiment with in order to get just the string to be passed. Unfortunately, none of them worked. Here is the start of the code for the ProcessCheckBox sub:

```
'Sub to process when a checkbox has been changed.
Sub ProcessCheckBox(ByVal rowPos As Integer, ByVal colPos As Integer, ByVal currentSheet As String)
'Sub ProcessCheckBox(ByVal currentSheet As String)

MsgBox currentSheet

'Declares a worksheet object named currentSheet.
Dim activeSheet As Worksheet
'Sets currentSheet equal to the active worksheet.
Set activeSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(currentSheet)
'Set currentSheet = ActiveSheet
```

After clicking the checkbox, a msgbox appears that is completely blank, and then I run into an error where it says the subscript is out of range.

I gather from this that the sub is being called, the String value is just not being passed along. The string value in the first sub (currentName) does have a value, as I can print it out and use it for calculations just fine.

I think the problem is in the OnAction line itself. It took me a while to figure out how to pass the integer values due to not knowing the correct number of single and double quotes to use. I think it has to do with this, however, all of the other examples I saw passed String values like this. I even experimented by adding or removing quotes just to see if it would work out and nothing.

Other errors I thought it might be: a sub has a limit to how many/large parameters can be passed to it, only parameters of a single type can be passed (either String or Integer). Neither of these make sense because I have encountered many examples that pass much more data across many different types to a sub.

Thank you to the people who answered, but neither of the solutions offered worked. I've been testing the macro and it appears no matter what I do, it will not pass a string as a parameter, either alone or with other parameters. I don't know why.

Here are the two lines in question I have narrowed it down to :

```
.OnAction = "'ProcessCheckBox " & colPos + 1 & "," & rowPos + 1 + i & ",""" & nameSheet & """'"
```

And the first line of the sub :

```
Sub ProcessCheckBox(ByVal colPos As Integer, ByVal rowPos As Integer, ByVal sheetName As String)
```

Ticking the checkbox gives me an error saying "Argument Not Optional." However, it doesn't allow me to go into debug mode, and it doesn't highlight the specific line either, although I have tested it and believe these two lines to be the problem.

Comment: Check if `",""" & currentName & """'"` works. And make sure that you set a value for `currentName`, because right now this variable is empty.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't. I already tried that combination. Thanks for responding though.

Comment: Actually, it was the first suggestion, .OnAction = "'ProcessCheckBox " & rowPos + 1 & "," & colPos + 1 + i & ",""" & currentSheet & """'", that solved it. I must have missed a quote somewhere. Thanks @Pᴇʜ

Comment: I've just realised a new bug has occurred. When looping through and creating the checkboxes, only the first checkbox activates the macro. The rest of the checkboxes (a dozen or so) don't do anything when clicked, except for unchecking the only functioning checkbox.

Comment: If you have a new question then please open a new question and describe your issue more detailed or give a [mcve] with an example.

Comment: Ok sure. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've given up on figuring VBA's single and double quotes and acknowledge that I never needed anything to be passed as argument that wasn't available in the workbook in which the check box resides. Therefore I can easily get all the information I might want to pass directly from the worksheet.

Where that may not be enough, I also get access to the CheckBox object itself. All my needs for arguments can be satisfied completely without any quotation marks.

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()

    Dim ChkBox As Shape

    Set ChkBox = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller)
    MsgBox ChkBox.Parent.Name & vbcr & _
           ChkBox.OLEFormat.Object.Name
End Sub
```

Here are 3 possible solutions for your problem, all involving the `Application.Caller`.
Please run this code on your project.

```
Sub CheckBox1_Click()

    Dim ChkBox As Shape
    Dim WsName As String, Rpos As Long, Cpos As Long
    Dim Cell As Range

    ' Solution 1
    WsName = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).OLEFormat.Object.Parent.Name
    MsgBox "You already know how to pass the cell coordinates" & vbCr & _
           "Just get the Sheet name from here:" & vbCr & _
           "Sheet name is """ & WsName & """"

    Set ChkBox = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller)
    ' Solution 2
    Set Cell = ChkBox.OLEFormat.Object.TopLeftCell
    Rpos = Cell.Row
    Cpos = Cell.Column
    WsName = Cell.Worksheet.Name
    MsgBox "Solution 2" & vbCr & _
           "The checkbox Top Left is aligned with the" & vbCr & _
           "Linked Cell's Top Left:-" & vbCr & _
           "Row number = " & Rpos & vbCr & _
           "Column number = " & Cpos & vbCr & _
           "Worksheet name = " & WsName & vbCr & _
           "If Alignment of underlying cell and TopLeft" & vbCr & _
           "isn't perfect, modify the placement in your other code." & vbCr & _
           "Here is the TopLeft address:-" & vbCr & _
           "TopLeftCell address = " & Cell.Address


    ' Solution 3
    Set Cell = Range(ChkBox.OLEFormat.Object.LinkedCell)
    Rpos = Cell.Row
    Cpos = Cell.Column
    WsName = Cell.Worksheet.Name
    MsgBox "Solution 3" & vbCr & _
           "Get the information directly from the Linked Cell." & vbCr & _
           "(This is probably the one you are interested in):-" & vbCr & _
           "Row number = " & Rpos & vbCr & _
           "Column number = " & Cpos & vbCr & _
           "Worksheet name = " & WsName & vbCr & _
           "This method might fail if the linked cell" & vbCr & _
           "is altered, perhaps manually."
End Sub
```

Comment: I think I may need to go this route, as the solution above did what I wanted it to do, but has now introduced a new bug.

Comment: Unfortunately this answer did not work due to the way my project is structured. Thanks for answering though.

Comment: Can I be of any help?

Comment: Sure. I just edited the question with some new info, thanks.

Comment: I have worked out 3 solutions and added the code to my answer above. Run this code from your project without any arguments being passed.

Comment: Wow. Thank you for such a comprehensive reply. I have a working solution but this will definitely help me learn going forward. Thank you.